# Using GetLine with ifstream - no instance of "getline" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, wifstream

I am trying to figure this problem out, for some reason I keep getting this:

> no instance of "getline" matches the argument list.

I have looked up this problem and a lot of times its because people use ofstream, or they don't use the ifstream object (if I said that right) has the first attribute to getline. I am quite lost.

```
        #include <string>

        std::wifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("LaunchLocations.txt");
        getline(myfile, gameLaunchtest.directory);
```

---

```
struct gameLaunch
{
    wchar_t directory[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t AppName[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t ComboBoxName[MAX_PATH];

}gameLaunchtest;
```

Comment: did you mean `std::getline()` there?

Comment: And is `directory` declared as `std::wstring`?

Comment: I tried to use getline from include <string> 

But I have also used std::getline (idk if they are the same, I am pretty new to C++ programming) 

But anyways, when I did std::getline I receive the error: 
no instance of overloaded function "std::getline" matches the argument list

Comment: @Remy Lebeau the directory is declared as wchar_t. So it's a wide null terminated string. (Hopefully I said that right)

Comment: [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does not support reading into a `wchar_t[]` array, only into a `std::string` or `std::wstring`, depending on the input stream type. To read into a `wchar_t[]`, you need to use the [`std::wifstream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) method instead, eg: `myfile.getline(gameLaunchtest.directory, MAX_PATH);`  You really should be using `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t[]`, though (and why are you using `MAX_PATH` for things that are not file paths?).

Comment: @TrevinCorkery all the standard functions are in the std namespace, so you should only use `std::getline()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does not support reading into a `wchar_t[]` array, only into a `std::string` or `std::wstring` (depending on the input stream type). To read into a `wchar_t[]`, you need to use the [`std::wifstream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) method instead:

```
myfile.getline(gameLaunchtest.directory, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: Thanks :) did me wonders! It was probably a noob mistake I just like using wchar_t because it's really simple and straightforward to work with Win32 Api. 
I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @TrevinCorkery use `std::wstring` instead of wchar_t array, and use its `.c_str()` member function when you need to pass string to a WinAPI function